# How can I perform a mouse click at certain cursor position using a KeyUp key?

Tags: c#, wpf

So in the constructor I have this

`KeyUp += WindowKeyUp;`

and in the methods I have this, where the *x* and *y* is a point I get from another method.

```
private void DoMouseClick(int x, int y)
{
    SetCursorPos(x, y);
    mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0);
}
```

So what I should write here to perform the mouse click at that particular cursor position when I release the Spacebar?

```
private void WindowKeyUp(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Space)
    {
       //what to write here?
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *"what to write here?"* - only you know. Do you want to call method?

Comment: You need to call DoMouseClick over there

Comment: The only complication seems to be where you put those x and y co-ordinates between getting them from wherever they come from and calling your method. Assuming both will be in the same class.

Comment: I guess you have [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)

Answer (score 0):

I somehow agree that this may be a XY problem. But since we don't know the real use case behind it, I will show how you can get the last x and y.

You can react on mouse move event to store the x and y and use that information when you receive the key up event.

Her is the XAML part:

```
<StackPanel KeyDown="StackPanel_KeyDown" MouseMove="StackPanel_MouseMove">
```

Here are the handlers:
        private void DoMouseClick(double x, double y)
        {
            //...
        }

```
    private double m_x = 0.0;
    private double m_y = 0.0;
    private void StackPanel_MouseMove(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var p = e.GetPosition(this);
        m_x = p.X;
        m_y = p.Y;
    }

    private void StackPanel_KeyDown(object sender, System.Windows.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == System.Windows.Input.Key.Space) {
            DoMouseClick(m_x, m_y);
        }
    }
```